# Can't disable subscription tracking for SendGrid emails

Tags: email, sendgrid

We used to use the Sendgrid unsubscribe groups, with links appended to the footer of our emails. We now have in app unsubscribe configurations, meaning we dont want the SendGrid unsubscribes anymore.

[Subscription tracking is disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUUf3.png), but we are still getting the SendGrid footer [automatically appended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOmxo.png) to every email. Is there something I should be doing here that I'm not to get rid of this link?

Answer (score 0):

Subscription tracking is something different, that's why you still see the unsubscribe link in the email.

Try [using a custom unsubscribe link](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/create-and-manage-unsubscribe-groups#using-a-custom-unsubscribe-link) as described in the docs.